# git-svn with file-based access to repository

Tags: git, git-svn

I get the following error when I try to git clone an SVN repository:

```
$ git svn clone "file:////stevenagefs/Projects/6500-6999/6792/DesignSVNRepos" 
"DesignGit" -T trunk -b branches -t tags -r 0:HEAD
Couldn't open a repository: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL: Unable to
 open repository 'file:///stevenagefs/Projects/6500-6999/6792/DesignSVNRepos' at
  C:\Apps\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 2210
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is it not possible to use git-svn like this?

Note that I know that file-based access to SVN repositories is considered harmful, but that's all I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed file-access, but only if the client is compiled with file-access support (`ra_local`), which `git-svn` does not seem to be. If you really want file-access you will need to build your own `git-svn` client.

Comment: You can also run `svnserve -d` temporarily and then perform the `clone` operation against `svn://localhost/path`.